# How can I make my Google App Script wait for an answer in telegram bot then run the if statement?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, telegram-bot

How do I make my Google App Script wait for an answer in telegram bot and run my `if` statement afterwards?

My idea of the code is:
When I type `/survey`, it will run the following code which will post a question, "how are you?". The script will wait for me to type any text, afterwards run my `if` statement when the answer is typed in.

```
function survey(data){
  var Q1 = {
    'chat_id': data.message.chat.id,
    'text': 'how are you?'
  }
  var method = 'sendMessage';
  var options = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    'payload' : JSON.stringify(Q1)
  }
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.telegram.org/bot' + telegramToken + '/' + method, options);

var text = data.message.text;
if(text == ""){
   currentstep = '3'; //need help here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Promises** or **async/await**, in this way your **IF** statement will wait for response from **API** and executed as soon you get response.

```
async function survey(data){
  var Q1 = {
    'chat_id': data.message.chat.id,
    'text': 'how are you?'
  }
  var method = 'sendMessage';
  var options = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    'payload' : JSON.stringify(Q1)
  }
  var response = await UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.telegram.org/bot' + telegramToken + '/' + method, options);

var text = data.message.text;
if(text == ""){
   currentstep = '3'; //need help here
}
```

**OR**

```
function survey(data){
  var Q1 = {
    'chat_id': data.message.chat.id,
    'text': 'how are you?'
  }
  var method = 'sendMessage';
  var options = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    'payload' : JSON.stringify(Q1)
  }
  UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.telegram.org/bot' + telegramToken + '/' + method, options).then((data)=>{
var text = data.message.text;
if(text == ""){
   currentstep = '3'; //need help here
}
})
}
```

Comment: Hi sir, i am still unable to run my if statement even though i have changed my code into yours. Is there any other methods?

Comment: Your issue is your IF statement not waiting for `UrlFetchApp.fetch()`'s response, am i right ?

Comment: hi. My telegram bot is able to post ‘how are you?, which is my urlfetchapp. My problem is that i want to reply to that question which then can run my if statement in which allowing my current step to be defined as ‘3’. 

Sorry if my question wasn’t phrased properly.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what can accommodate your needs is the [**reply_markup**](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage) parameter with [**ForceReply**](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#forcereply), available in almost all send methods in the Telegram Bot API. As mentioned:

> **ForceReply** can be extremely useful if you want to create user-friendly
> step-by-step interfaces without having to sacrifice privacy mode

You can see a sample JSON response from ForceReply [**here**](https://github.com/silikidi/Telegram-JSON-Response/blob/main/TEXT-REPLY.json). Based on that structure, do the same thing by calling **data.message.text** to get the results of user input from ForceReply.

```
if ( (( data || {} ).message || {}).text ){
  
  if ( data.message.text === "/start" ) {
  
    var dataForceReply = {
      method: "post",
      payload: {
        method: "sendMessage",
        chat_id: String( data.message.chat.id ),
        text: "how are you?",
        reply_markup: JSON.stringify({
          "force_reply": true
        })
      }
    };
    UrlFetchApp.fetch( telegramAPIURL + "/", dataForceReply );

  } else { //Assumed the user gives input
    
    var text = data.message.text;
    
    if ( text === "" ) {
      var currentstep = "3";
    } else {
      //Process according to your needs
    }

  }

}
```